# new Intenso 64GB stick not working in Linux, I/O-error, works fine in Windows 10 [WON'T FIX, HARDWARE INCOMPATIBLE]

Tags: usb, kernel, usb-drive

**TLDR: Make sure to buy USB sticks that are certified to run on Linux, as some brand new ones might not be compatible in 2023.**

This is a tough one. I bought a brand new usb pen drive (Intenso 64GB, USB 3.2) from a store, it works fine under Windows 10, and I even reformatted it there from exFAT to NTFS, and I can save files on it. But neither way it is mountable or even accessible in Linux.

- it does not show up in lsusb
- it does not make the plug-in sound when pluggin it in
- it does not work on a different usb port or a different computer
- it does not show up in gparted
- all other usb sticks I own work fine

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep sdd
    [    4.645248] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 123473920 512-byte logical blocks: (63.2 GB/58.9 GiB)
    [    4.645906] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
    [    4.645907] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
    [    4.646567] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
    [    4.651163]  sdd: sdd1
    [    4.653428] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
    [   48.621177] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=43s
    [   48.621182] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 07 5c 0f fc 00 00 01 00
    [   48.621185] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 123473916 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
    [   48.636415] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 123473912 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
    [   48.644051] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 15434239, async page read
```

my linux kernel is 5.15.0-67-generic.

so I am clueless whether

- it is an intenso problem
- it is a 64GB related problem
- it is a USB gen 3.2 problem?

Update: on Amazon the 32GB version is shown as Linux compatible, while with the 64GB version, Linux is not listed. I didn't even know USB sticks could need more than the default drivers, but obviously, it is too new and for some reason there is no driver for the 64GB variant!?

Comment: Why ask here?  You've provided no OS/release details and thus is a Ubuntu Q&A site, you only mention Linux which is supported on SE *Unix & Linux*  Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry, I a don't know where else to post, as stack-exchange says it is programming related only. Maybe you could give me a hint where a post would be better. However, there could be lots of Ubuntu users affected if this is some kind of new driver issue.

Comment: You mentioned your linux kernel, and your paste included `ubuntu@ubuntu` as $USER@$HOSTNAME as your likely $PS1 prompt... Why not take my *hint* and correct your question to reference Ubuntu (not Linux), and provide details as to what Ubuntu product you're asking about.. ie. following the rules in the on-topic link I provided.  Stack Exchange has a *Unix & Linux* site that covers Linux which I mentioned in my first comment if you want to ask Linux questions (*as your question was worded*)

Comment: Alright, I am posting now on Stack Exchange. Will leave this discussion open in case we get a solution.

Comment: Stack Exchange does not allow posting the same question on more than one of its sites... thus you'll have to remove this question first (*before asking on SE Unix & Linux*) otherwise you'll be breaking more SE rules.. You risk having your newer question closed as duplicate of this & this closed as off-topic (*when it's closed it can then be migrated to SE Unix & Linux*).  Please try and stay with Stack Exchange network rules.

Comment: You've still not provided any Ubuntu product/release details. Some Ubuntu products provide kernel stack options which can allow you to change kernel & kernel modules (kernel modules being commonly called *drivers*) thus details about your system are essential...

Comment: Hi, guiverc, it is a Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon (the most recent, LTS), and I just updated the kernel to 5.15.0-71-generic. Linux Mint 21 is based on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Sorry Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, but quite different, and you should ask about it at a Linux Mint forum or at 'Unix and Linux' (and in that case delete your post here).

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: Alright, I will close this issue now. I think the Mint community is even smaller than the Ubuntu community and will not have the resources to tackle (in my believe, universal) hardware problems like this. I update the question accordingly.

Comment: @kenbi sure but their forums have users that created Mint so they know the ins and outs. ALL my usb (and I have sticks from 4Gb to 256Gb from amazon and all work on linux; most are sandisk and lexar). The U means universal and the universal includes windows :+

Comment: Don't forget Linux Mint has an additional layer of software that Ubuntu does **not** include (the runtime *adjustments* that allow them to use *foreign* Ubuntu packages). Ubuntu upgrades make no allowance for them, which means some *adjustments* need tweaking after security patches flow through from Ubuntu - these are usually evident on screen; but you're off-topic asking about those here; as Ubuntu & *flavors* all have write access to Ubuntu repositories, thus they don't use adjustments.